# How can I use the new MUI look & Feel?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

A simple question, but can't find the way.
How can I install mui and use the theme / look and feel showed in the mui homepage?:

[Here new look and feel material ui screnshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg4PT.jpg)

because, after create my project and install mui using:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

I see the classic material design like this:

[Here current classic material design example buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjdOW.png)

Comment: MUI only provides commonly used components by default. You can customize on your own or try [these components](https://mui-treasury.com/)

Comment: Are you migrating from Mui v4? If so you need to update your component imports. `import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';` would become `import { Button } from '@mui/material';` Check the migration guide, there's a codemod you can run to do it.

Comment: Im not doing a migration, Im installing mui from scratch. But Im not able to use the new design components.

I know I can customize the template as I want, but I can't understand how mui shows a component style in its home that it doesn't provide ...

Is that so?

Comment: Have you tried using `npm install @mui/material@latest @emotion/react@latest @emotion/styled@latest` ? or @next (in place of latest)?

Answer (score 0):

As of now you can't (at least without buying any custom theme from the store).

They use their internal custom theme built over MUI, if you go inside the MUI landing page and scroll down you can switch between their custom theme and the standard one.